# Скрытие выпадающего меню по клику вне

Tags: меню, jquery, javascript

Делаю выпадающие менюшки, хочу чтоб при клике в любое место вне менюшки, она пропадала. Есть какое-то умное решение? Или придется делать два контейнера с менюшками и со всем остальным и на него вешать событие онклик, чтоб закрывалась менюшка? Нужно как можно динамичнее, чтобы несколько менюшек делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то примерно так

```
$('.menu').click(function () {
    // Показываем выпадающее меню

    $('body').click(function () {
        // Прячем выпадающее меню
    });
});
```

**Вариант**.

Разметка

```
<a class="menu" href="#">Меню</a>
<div class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
    <div><a href="#">Выбор 1</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Выбор 2</a></div>
</div>
```

Код

```
$('.menu').click(function () {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
    $(this).next().show();
    return false;
});
$('body, .dropdown a').click(function () {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
});
$('.dropdown a').click(function () {
    // TODO: Что-то сделать
});
```

Comment: Этот же метод тоже не правильно работает. Вроде бы все правильно, но он кнопку открыть меню тоже считает за body и сразу же его закрывает, а нужно чтобы при нажатие на выпадающее меню ничего не происходило.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть какое-то умное решение?

Есть, написать OnClick() и hide тот блок который не нужен

Comment: По-точнее бы, такое решение предлагали. Но не работает или не корректно. Да и нужно чтобы легко можно было новые менюшки добавлять.

Comment: Пробовал вот так, но  почему то не работает:
$('#wrap').click(function() {
$('#MyProfile').hide();
 });

Прежде чем скрывать блок, его нужно показать. Таких функции не работают, потому что он не может показать блок, он его скрывает сразу, что даже не успевает открыться.

Comment: "такое решение предлагали" - а самому сесть, подумать и написать уже не?

Или сейчас новая мода на "программистов мышкой"?

Comment: во-во-во-во

Comment: Жесть в том, что уже несколько часов сижу. Вроде сделал как надо. Должно работать. Но не работает. Десятки вариантов перепробовал.

Comment: "уже несколько часов сижу" - о да... Вы типа пытались...

Answer (score 0):

Искал решение аналогичной задаче, получился такой вариант:

Разметка:

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <a class="menu" href="#">Меню</a>
    <ul class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="#">Подменю 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Подменю 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Код:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // В класс "page" обернуто все содержимое страницы. 
    // Можно повесить событие и на body, но тогда это меню не будет работать на I-pad
    jQuery('.page').click(function( event ){
        // проверяем находится ли элемент на который кликнули в нашем меню,
        // то есть в контейнере "menu-container"
        var eventInMenu = $( event.target ).parents('.menu-container');

        // если родителя нет, значит клик был вне меню и меню сворачиваем
        if( !eventInMenu.length ){
            $('.dropdown').hide();
        }
    });

    jQuery('.menu-container').click(function(){
        $('.dropdown').show();
    });
});
```